# find range of substring of string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to get a range of a substring within a string. By range I mean where the substring begins and where it ends. So if I have following string example:

```
NSString *testString=@"hello everyone how are you doing today?Thank you!";
```

If the substring I am looking for (in this example) is "how are you doing", then the beginning range should be 15 and the ending range should 31.

```
  (15, 31)
```

Can anyone tell me how I could do this programatically? Thank you!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the method `-rangeOfString` to find the location of a substring in a string. You can then compare the location of the range to NSNotFound to see if the string actually does contain the substring.

```
NSRange range = [testString rangeOfString:@"how are you doing"];

if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"The string (testString) does not contain 'how are you doing' as a substring");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Found the range of the substring at (%d, %d)", range.location, range.location + range.length);        
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you always check that range.location is different from NSNotFound.

Answer (score 12):

It is pretty straight forward. You say you want to search the string "hello everyone how are you doing today?Thank you!" for "how are you doing".

You say you need the position of the first character and the last.

```
NSString *testString=@"hello everyone how are you doing today?Thank you!";

NSRange range = [testString rangeOfString:@"how are you doing"];

NSUInteger firstCharacterPosition = range.location;
NSUInteger lastCharacterPosition = range.location + range.length;
```

So now you have it those two last variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in method part of `NSString`:

```
[testString rangeOfString:@"hello how are you doing"]
```

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_