# How do I get position of character in NSString?

Tags: ios

I have this NSString

```
Asia/Tokyo
```

I want to get only "Tokyo" by removing "Asia/" I know it will get to work by searching for the position of "/" but how do i do that? pls help

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the location of a substring in a string :

```
[@"Asia/Tokyo" rangeOfString:@"/"].location
```

Comment: Note this will find the *first* instance of the substring. You can use `rangeOfString:options:range` if you want to find other instances, or search backwards, or other things covered by the options.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this as well:

```
NSString *mainString = @"Asia/Tokyo";

NSUInteger location = [mainString rangeOfString:@"/"].location + 1;

NSLog(@"Trimed string:%@",[mainString substringFromIndex:location]);
```

Result: Trimed string:Tokyo

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string with `componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"`  This'll return an array, and you just grab the second element.

Comment: That's overkill when you simply need the index of a character.

Comment: Unless this is performance-critical code, `[input componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"][1]` is a perfectly good solution.

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, it works but the thought of scanning the entire string for the delimiter, creating a temporary array full of strings I don't actually need, just to get the index of a character, makes me shiver.

Comment: @rmaddy Although the question was how to get the index, the OP isn't actually trying to get the position of the character, he's trying to get the substring delimited by the character.

Comment: @David Then use `substringFromIndex:` to get the needed substring after getting the range of the delimiter.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the underlying problem as efficiently as possible.  The OP's technique works but it's a bit naive an non-Cocoa-ideomatic.  It's always better for your code to respect the underlying semantic of the data, and this data doesn't use character offsets and ranges in a meaningful way, so you end up having to do lots of checks when the data is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rangeOfString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) to give you the location of string. I would also run the range through an if statement looking for NSNotFound just in case the string you are looking for isn't found.

[Check out this answer for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998478/find-range-of-substring-of-string)